# Can't read json from file in Qt

Tags: json, qt

I have a problem when reading JSON file with Qt. My app:

```
QFile jsonFile("data.json");
if (!jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug() << "Nie udało sie otworzyc pliku";
    return;
}

auto jsonBytes = jsonFile.readAll();
auto document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonBytes);
if (document.isNull()) {
    QJsonObject *jsonObject = new QJsonObject(document.object());
    qDebug() << "null";
    return;
}
```

Json in data.json is valid, I checked it with a validator. The problem is that document is null and can't figure out why.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is the JSON file? Is your program running in the same directory or has that in its path?

Comment: The JSON file is in the same folder where the app is and is read correctly into a jsonFile.

Comment: Your JSON file probably is encoded in different format than UTF-8 and contains some special characters (like ę, ą, etc.). You need to either change encoding of JSON file to UTF-8 or make an attempt to convert the read string in your application.

Comment: Replace `jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)` with `jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)`.

Comment: May be you have comments in json file?

Comment: Ok, It turned out to be a stupid mistake, I had a comma at the end of my json file. I was sure it's valid because the validator I was checking it with had an option to automatically fix json and then showed it as VALID. Sorry for my oversight and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this a lot and it usually works well, so:

Check if the file exists. Written like this, it is relative to the working directory.

```
qDebug() << QFile::exists("data.json");
```

Check if the JSON parsing runs without error:

```
QJsonParseError error;
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonBytes, &error);
qDebug() << error.errorString();
```